# How can I access these functions on the derived class?

Tags: c++, function, oop, object

class A has a member function fx1
class B has member function fx1
class Z is derived from class X and class Y. 
If obj is an object of class Z, How will you access these functions.

Comment: Did you misspell "A" and "B" as "X" and "Y"?